# Load test on Azure

Tags: azure, jmeter, load-testing, azure-cloud-services

I am running a load test using JMeter on my Azure web services.
I scale my services on S2 with 4 instances and run JMeter 4 instances with 500 threads on each.

It starts perfectly fine but after a while calls start failing and giving Timeout error (HTTP status:500).

I have checked HTTP request queue on azure and found that on 2nd instance it is very high and two instances it is very **low**.

Please help me to success my load test.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Azure App Service. If you check the settings of your App, you will notice ARR’s Instance Affinity will be enabled by default. A brief explanation:

> ARR cleverly keeps track of connecting users by giving them a special cookie (known as an affinity cookie), which allows it to know, upon subsequent requests, to which server instance they were talking to. This way, we can be sure that once a client establishes a session with a specific server instance, it will keep talking to the same server as long as his session is active.

This is an important feature for session-sensitive applications, but if it's not your case then you can safely disable it to improve the load balance between your instances and avoid situations like the one you've described.

[Disabling ARR’s Instance Affinity in Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to caching of network names resolution on JVM or OS level so all your requests are hitting only one server. If it is the case - add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan and it should resolve your issue.

See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) article for more detailed explanation and configuration instructions.